# Cant get access $scope variable data in my page and display using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, playframework

I'm trying to do a POC using Angular JS, Playframework and Mongo DB [one week old in all of them]. I have exposed the data using REST services. I am trying to query the users stored in my DB using the Java script code shown below. The data is getting fetched and am able to see it in a JS alert. But I just cant get it to show up on my webpage though!

I am not sure what's wrong! I have posted the JS as well as the skeleton of my webpage below. I have removed most part from the page here, but either way, I cannot get the data to show up. Any help would he highly appreciated.

I got the whole site working using Play framework's default format (Result object, if I am not wrong), but that's not what I was looking for. What am I doing wrong or am I missing something? Please let me know if you need more data.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
 
$http.get("/users").success(function(response) {
 $scope.res = JSON.stringify(response);
});

});
```

```html
@(tickets: List[Ticket], ticketForm: Form[Ticket])

@import helper._

@main("Defect Tracking System") {

 <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
      
 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="appCtrl">
     
    <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="x in res">
     {{ x.userName }}
   </li>
 </ul>
  
 </div>
 
 <script src= "assets/controller.js"></script>
}
```

Comment: `$scope.res = JSON.stringify(response);` you are converting the result to a string. If it is a list you only have to do `$scope.res = response;`. Post an example of the data you receive from the http call

Comment: `[{"id":"55a2357fb8aeaa3746e35fd5","userName":"Naveen"},{"id":"55a2357fb8aeaa3746e35fd6","userName":"Kumar"},{"id":"55a2357fb8aeaa3746e35fd7","userName":"Kalapati"},{"id":"55a2357fb8aeaa3746e35fd8","userName":"Reddeppa"},{"id":"55a2357fb8aeaa3746e35fd9","userName":"Rajeswari"}]`

This is my JSON data. Even if I remove the JSON.stringify, I still cannot get it to work. I guess I've tried all the tricks.